# Random access to array element

Tags: batch-file

I'm simply trying to access a random element from a defined array:

```
@set DIRs[0]="%APPDATA%"
@set DIRs[1]="%APPDATA%\testapp"
@set DIRs[2]="%APPDATA%\testapp2"

@set /a _rand=(%RANDOM% * 2 /32768)+1 

echo %_rand%
echo !DIRs[%%_rand]!
```

I guess that random generator (it prints always `2`) and the last line are both wrong.

Comment: Why are you doing `echo !DIRs[%%_rand]!` instead of `echo !DIRs[%_rand%]!`?  The `%%` notation is for iterators, like in a `for %%I in...` loop.

Comment: `Set /a num=%random% %% %Count% + 1` where count is the range you want. if `5` it means a range of `0-4` and the `+1` makes it `1-5`. `%%` is escaping a single `%` and is modulus division (ie the remainder).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's

```
echo !DIRs[%_rand%]!
```

(assumig you have `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`)

If you need to do it without delayed expansion, use this trick to get another layer of parsing:

```
call echo %%DIRs[%_rand%]%%
```

Comment: what's the usual way to access an array using a variable as index without `enabledelayedexpansion`?

Comment: DelayedExpansion means it is evaluated when executed. Normal expansion is when the line is read. So if within brackets without delayed expansion the value is always what it was when the line (which can be multiple if brackets are used) was read. Hence changes to the variable can't be picked up within the line.

Comment: @alfredopacino there is no "usual" way, because technically, arrays does not exist in batch (or there are - depends whom you ask). Nevertheless, added the "usual"  trick to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Stephan is correct regarding the syntax of accessing array indices.

The reason why your random number is always 2 is that when using CMD the seed of the random function is defined by execution time of your script. From ss64.com:

> **Random vs Pseudorandom numbers**
>
> A pseudorandom sequence is not truly random but is determined by a small set of initial values (state), the initial seed is often based on the clock time. In the case of the CMD %RANDOM% the seed is based on the clock time when the CMD session started. This can be problematic when running a batch file, if the script always takes about the same time to run before calling %RANDOM% then the number returned will always lie within a small predictable range.

Source: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html